# Is it possible to simulate device orientation in a playground?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Given this scenario:

```
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = TableViewController()
```

Would it be possible to simulate the device's orientation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some logic found in [here](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/blob/5707e8b6f26ce467fbdebe74ffc544fa257b7a00/Classes/KIFSystemTestActor.m#L59-L62) the [KIF testing framework](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF), I suppose it should be possible.

The Objective-C code behind the link looks like this:

```objc
- (void)simulateDeviceRotationToOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:orientation] forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

The Swift equivalent of this code would look like this:

```swift
func simulateDeviceRotation(toOrientation orientation: UIDeviceOrientation) {
    let orientationValue = NSNumber(integer: orientation.rawValue)
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(orientationValue, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

And then we'd just call it something like this:

```
simulateDeviceRotation(toOrientation: .LandscapeLeft)
```

Or perhaps we want a function that runs some code for each orientation?

```
func forEachOrientation(block: () -> Void) {
    for orientation in [UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait, UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft, UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown, UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight] {
        simulateDeviceRotation(toOrientation: orientation)
        block()
    }
}
```

And we can just call it like this:

```
forEachOrientation {
    // do a thing
}
```

From my experience, this actually doesn't seem to work on iOS 9 simulators, but it does work on iOS 8 simulators.  I don't know whether or not this would work on real devices.